# Robocraft blimp

Tags: robocraft

I have a tier 4 blimp with 3 rail gun, I always get spotted and shot, is there anyway I can avoid being seen? 
And I haven't seen any blimp since the update, is it just useless?

Answer (score 3):

Blimps begin to get useless around tier 4+ because that's when people begin to look up to see planes and blimps. If you still want to stay with the blimp, putting electroplates on your bot is a good idea, because they can take about 1 rail shot from the same tier (2 to destroy) and a few SMG shots. Also, headlights make it harder for snipers to hit you, because their guns get blinded when they are looking straight at a headlight. I hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I have found for this is to add the ghost module, but if you don't have it, I would try to make it smaller, or make it faster so when they do see you, you can get away faster.

Answer (score -2):

if you are using helium it's completely useless because when in the air you go slowly up and down, decreasing the aim of the rail gun making it useless. if you change weapons, add more cubes and helium you can fly down and fight like a tank.

Comment: This does not answer the question. You've stated the uselessness of a Blimp, but haven't addressed how to stay "less visible".